# Unexpected error OutOfMemory on Azure VM but there about 47% of free memory

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I've got D2s_v3 VM in Azure on Windows. According to the specification it has got 2vCPU and 8RAM. I faced with a problem that it constantly use about 50% of RAM. On 54% of RAM consumption I cannot open any app due to memory preasure and any PowerShell fails with OutOfMemory error.
Task manager shows that I use only 54% of available RAM but at the same time Commited RAM shows as 10Gb/10Gb (full).

How can I configure VM to allow use whole range of RAM?

Comment: Check if you are running a 64bit OS and a 64bit JVM.

Comment: It's OK - Win Server Datacenter x64. I've posted issue for Azure support.

Comment: What about your JVM version? If your JVM is x86, your x64 OS won't help much.